# RadioGroup not visible ball

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, radio-button, radio-group

i have problem with my XML.

My XML not show ball near textview.

I show you my code.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/chk_box_tavolo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_tavolo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
<!--</LinearLayout>-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Textview as a child to radioGroup, which should be radio button. Here is a neat example of android radio button.

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RadioGroup then child must be RadioButton, instead of textview use RadioButton. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html)

> To create each radio button option, create a RadioButton in your
>   layout. However, because radio buttons are mutually exclusive, you
>   must group them together inside a RadioGroup. By grouping them
>   together, the system ensures that only one radio button can be
>   selected at a time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/chk_box_tavolo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioMale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="male"
        android:checked="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```